# XSLT: Select succeeding tags into child segments until next tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following input XML. The successive E_Records are optional and it should be populated into L_Record. I have written the below XSLT coding. Is there any changes should i have to do?

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Record>
     <H_Record>
        <Rec_Type>H</Rec_Type>
     </H_Record>
     <C_Record>
        <Rec_Type>C</Rec_Type>
     </C_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>3</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>4</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <R_Record>
        <Rec_Type>R</Rec_Type>
     </R_Record>
  </Record>
  <Record>
     <H_Record>
        <Rec_Type>H</Rec_Type>
     </H_Record>
     <C_Record>
        <Rec_Type>C</Rec_Type>
     </C_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>1</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>2</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>5</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>6</E_Qty>
     </E_Record>
     <R_Record>
        <Rec_Type>R</Rec_Type>
     </R_Record>
  </Record>
```

The Output XML i am expecting is

```
 <Record>
   <H_Record>
        <Rec_Type>H</Rec_Type>
   </H_Record>
   <C_Record>
        <Rec_Type>C</Rec_Type>
   </C_Record>
   <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
      <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>3</E_Qty>
      </E_Record>
      <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>4</E_Qty>
      </E_Record>
    </L_Record>
    <L_Record>
       <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
       <L_Level>2</L_Level>
    </L_Record>
    <R_Record>
       <Rec_Type>R</Rec_Type>
    </R_Record>
  </Record>
  <Record>
     <H_Record>
        <Rec_Type>H</Rec_Type>
     </H_Record>
     <C_Record>
        <Rec_Type>C</Rec_Type>
     </C_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>
     </L_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>      
       <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>1</E_Qty>
       </E_Record>
       <E_Record>
        <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
        <E_Qty>2</E_Qty>
       </E_Record>
     </L_Record>
     <L_Record>
        <Rec_Type>L</Rec_Type>
        <L_Level>2</L_Level>      
        <E_Record>
          <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
          <E_Qty>5</E_Qty>
        </E_Record>
        <E_Record>
          <Rec_Type>E</Rec_Type>
          <E_Qty>6</E_Qty>
        </E_Record>
    </L_Record>
    <R_Record>
        <Rec_Type>R</Rec_Type>
     </R_Record>
  </Record>
```

I have written the XSLT mapping for this as below but i am not getting the required output. Could you please help me on this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="L_Record">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node(),current-group()[self::E_Record]"/>          
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me on this?
When i am executing the above code, the C_Record and R_Record is being removed. How to populate that data in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach is to continue to use `for-each-group group-starting-with` but then, inside, to add an additional check whether you have a match (e.g. on `L_Record`):

```
  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="L_Record">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::L_Record">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node(),current-group()[self::E_Record]"/>          
                </xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::L_Record | self::E_Record)]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRApc/1 is the extension of the code sample from your previous question.

Comment: The code is working properly using Saxon processor. But the system which i wanted to deploy is not having Saxon processor and doesn't have external SAXON processor. does the input XML can be converted using XSLT 1.0 version?

Comment: @SrinivasBajina, perhaps, if you find someone wanting to do it in XSLT 1. It doesn't make muche sense to tag question as XSLT 2 to then change requirements.

Comment: :: My bad.The code is perfect, and i tried to debug and understood the code. But unfortunately, my application where i am deploying is not supporting SAXON processor. I will see if there is any process to install SAXON jar files into my application and also will find out ways if it can be done using XSLT 1.0.